# How to create left/right divs with text that varies in content length?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to do this:

[image]

This is the HTML/CSS that I have so far, but after trying various combinations of float, position absolute/relative, left, left-margin, clear, overflow, etc. I can't get it to handle varying lengths.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
        }
        .leftColumn {
            float:left;
        }
        .rightColumn {
            float:left;
            left:120px;
            position:absolute;
        }
        .clear {
            clear:both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="leftColumn">Apr 14: Title: </div>
        <div class="rightColumn">This is a text that will have a variable width, sometimes short and sometimes very, very long, sometimes short and sometimes very, very long.</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="leftColumn">Apr 15: Another Title: </div>
        <div class="rightColumn">This is a text that will have a variable width, sometimes short and sometimes very, very long, sometimes short and sometimes very, very long.</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="leftColumn">Apr 16: A Still Longer Title: </div>
        <div class="rightColumn">This is a text that will have a variable width, sometimes short and sometimes very, very long, sometimes short and sometimes very, very long.</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**What do I have to change to the a above CSS so that it handles variable length text in both columns as in the screenshot above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UHMtW/

1) Remove all those awful empty div for clearing of floats (just use `easyclearing` or some other not-structural equivalent technique)

2) You're missing all closing `</div>` for every `.rightColumn`

3) Use this css code [updated]

```
.container {
     height: auto; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;
     margin : 0 0 20px 0;
 }
 .leftColumn {
     float:left;
     width : 120px;
 }
 .rightColumn {
     margin-left: 120px;   
 }
```

of course change the width of the elements as you prefer and give some margin to `.container` elements

(As aside note I would suggest to use instead a description list `<dl>` but this would require to set a maximum height for the left columns. Or maybe you can avoid all that `<div>ification` using headings and paragraphs properly)

Comment: Thanks, one requirement I forgot to mention is that the right column needs to be variable width, filling out the available width of the browser, yet if I make the container width 100% or the right column width 100%, the right column nestles back under the left column. How can I get the right column to be variable width yet stay to the right of the its left column partner?

Comment: very enlightening that the right column has no float and there is no clear, works nicely, thanks